# missing FROM-clause entry for table rails custom model association

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, model, has-many, model-associations, belongs-to

I need to create custom association for one of my projects. I have provided custom class name and foreign key in model but still getting the error. Here is my code:

Comment Model:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :user
 belongs_to :portfolio, -> { where( comments: {comment_type: 'p'}) }, :foreign_key => :type_id, :class_name => 'Portfolio'
end
```

Portfolio Model:

```
class Portfolio < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :portfolio_details, :dependent => :destroy
 has_many :marks, -> { where(mark_type: 'p') }, :foreign_key => :type_id, :dependent => :destroy
 has_many :comments, -> { where(comment_type: 'p').order('id DESC') }, :foreign_key => :type_id, :dependent => :destroy
 has_many :likes, -> { where(like_type: 'p') }, :foreign_key => :type_id, :dependent => :destroy
 has_many :portfolio_files, -> { order 'portfolio_files.order' }, :dependent => :destroy
 belongs_to :category
 belongs_to :user
end
```

When I try to get portfolio details with association from comments table. it gives following error:

```
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "comments"

LINE 1: ...ROM "portfolios" WHERE "portfolios"."id" = $1 AND "comments"...                                                            ^

: SELECT  "portfolios".* FROM "portfolios" WHERE "portfolios"."id" = $1 AND "comments"."comment_type" = $2 LIMIT 1
```

Now how can I obtain portfolio detail for a comment. Please suggest.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: what you want to get portfolio or portfolio_details.?

Comment: does you have seperate model and table for portfolio_details?

Comment: I want to get portfolio model data. And yes I have separate model for portfolio_details.

Comment: can you please post your code which u have written to get portfolio data